# Difference between object oriented and object based language

Tags: javascript, oop

What is the difference between an object oriented and an object based programming language? Is JavaScript is an object oriented or based?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-based_language): *Object-based languages need not support inheritance or subtyping, but those that do are also said to be "object-oriented".(...) Sometimes the term "object-based" is applied to prototype-based languages, true object-oriented languages that do not have classes, but in which objects instead inherit their code and data directly from other "template" objects. An example of a commonly used prototype-based language is JavaScript.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-based) says:

> In computer science, the term object-based has two different senses:
>
> - A somehow limited version of object-oriented programming, where one or more of the following restrictions applies: (a) There is no implicit inheritance, (b) there is no polymorphism, (c) only a very reduced subset of the available values are objects (typically the GUI components).
> - Prototype-based systems (that is, those based on "prototype" objects that are not instances of any class).

Javascript is object based.

Comment: Well, JavaScript is prototype based, to answer the second part of the question.

Comment: So JavaScript is not object based but it is prototype based language rgt?

Comment: @Mark: Did you read the last sentence? *Javascript is object based.* Did you read my comment?

Comment: @Felix Yes I did. You said it's a prototype based not object based. Is object based & prototype based are same?

Comment: @Mark: The quote says that object-based is sometimes used describe prototype-based languages. JavaScript is prototype-based hence it is object-based.

Comment: I have to disagree with wikipedia's definition - an object-based language can have polymorphism, as different objects may respond to the same message with different behaviors. Inheritance is not required for polymorphism, only messaging.

Answer (score 3):

**Object Oriented** is based on message passing, no classes or inheritance involved.

"Object oriented" coined by Dr Alan Kay has been hijacked by
C++, Java and Co, Dr Alan Kay made it clear that OO was messages, not
classes.
Dr Alan Kay On OO 
"OOP to me means only messaging, local retention and protection and 
hiding of state-process, and extreme late-binding of all things."

Erlang, LISP, Smalltalk are OO programming languages, not C++, Java, c# etc which are in effect object based.

Answer (score 0):

**Object-oriented language**

Object-oriented language doesn't has in-built object. It has all feature of OOP. Object-oriented languages are C++, C#, Java etc

**Object-based language**

Object-based language doesn't support all the features of OOPs like Polymorphism and Inheritance. It has in-built object like javascript has window object.languages are Javascript, VB etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found there are two version of answer for this question.

Firstly, you must define what is object-oriented language.

1. From [English wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-based_language), you can find that class-based language is object-oriented language, and prototype-based language is not object-oriented language. They think if a language only uses "object" is not enough,so it is not an object-oriented language.
2. From [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS), you can find that prototype-based language is object-oriented language. Because they think if a language uses "object", it is an object-oriented language. And then they divide object-oriented into two type:

   - class-based and object-based object-oriented.
   - object-based(or prototype-based) object-oriented

---

My English is not very good. If  you are Chinese, you can see [Chinese wiki](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9F%BA%E4%BA%8E%E5%AF%B9%E8%B1%A1%E8%AF%AD%E8%A8%80).

Answer (score 0):

The following example is a general usage of a class in JavaScript:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v07Jd.png)

Result in the console:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtRid.png)

The **proto** references the Animals prototype (which in turn references the Object prototype).
From this, we can see that the constructor defines the major features while everything outside the constructor (sing() and dance()) are the bonus features (prototypes).

Comment: Please provide your code in code blocks, not as images. Images are hard to paste, and can break overtime, making this answer useless. Please move your code into your answer as plain text.