# Core difference between object oriented and object based language

Tags: java, javascript, oop, object

I want to know what is the core difference between

**Object Oriented and Object based languages**

I have read many post all of them are saying two things

1. Object-oriented language supports all the features of OOPs and Object-based language doesn't support all the features of OOPs like Polymorphism and Inheritance.
2. They are giving example of javascript as object based and java as object oriented

Like this post of stackoverflow

[Difference between object oriented and object based language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954293/difference-between-object-oriented-and-object-based-language)

But I want to know what is the core difference between both the concept regardless of any language.

Got the answer

Finally got the thing

thanks to `Matías Fidemraizer`

Answer which is not dependent on any language, not dependent on any feature, the core differnce for which I am loooking that is

*The language which itself contains objects is called as object based language and the language with follows object oriented concepts is known as object oriented language*

Comment: Can the down voter please gave me the answer

Comment: You're not right in your conclusion: Java, C# and almost any language has built-in objects. In fact, those have a top-most built-in object: `object` class, which is the implicitly base class of all objects. I mean, `Window` object is a built-in object in terms of "any browser implementation has a Window object`, but this fact doesn't define if it's object or object-oriented programming.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Just now you have said I am right

Answer (score 26, accepted):

JavaScript is a [prototype-oriented](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) language.

It can build actual objects from a constructor function and it has almost any feature that any object could have:

- Constructor.
- Methods (i.e. functions in JavaScript).
- Properties (since ECMA-Script 5, "getters/setters").
- Instances.

In JavaScript, any object has a *prototype*, including *functions*. The prototype itself is a rudimentary way of adding *object members* to any newly created instance of the whole object.

```
var constructor = function() { };
constructor.prototype.text = "hello world";

alert(new constructor().text); // This alerts hello world
```

Why JavaScript isn't an object-oriented programming *(scripting) language*? Because it has no feature that fits the requirements of the definition of object-oriented programming:

- **Polymorphism**: *No*. You can change the behavior of a prototype member, but this is just reusing the identifier. You aren't able to access the previous implementation of the member in a *pseudo-derived object*.
- **Inheritance**: *Not at all*. Maybe prototype chain might be comparable to inheritance but JavaScript (ECMA-Script 5.x or earlier versions) has no syntax-based inheritance like other OOP-based languages (i.e. Java, C#, Ruby, Python, VisualBasic.NET, ...).
- **Encapsulation**. Yes, of course, but there's no way to create actual private or internal object members.

Perhaps I forgot to mention some other detail, but I honestly believe that this is a good summary.

#### Update and summary

*The core difference is an object-oriented programming language has the features that an object-oriented paradigm must have in order to be considered an object-oriented programming language. **Thus, JavaScript, for now, isn't an actual object-oriented programming language because it lacks actual polymorphism and inheritance***.

### Update: Does ES2015 and above changed the situation?

Esthetically speaking yes, ES2015 and above has a major improvement that let consider a not fully but more closer to an object-oriented programming: syntactic sugar to call *to the super class*.

For example:

```
class A {
     doStuff() {
         console.log("hello world");
     }
}

class B extends A {
     doStuff() {
         super.doStuff();
         console.log("...and goodbye!");
     }
}
```

This is *polymorphism*. A more specialized class can override its base class to both completely change a function behavior or do what the base was already doing, adding new code to the function.

BTW, ES2015 and above still lacks true encapsulation: **where are access modifiers like `private` or `public` here?** *Nowhere*.

And, at the end of the day, ES2015 and above implement class-based OOP but it's still a syntactic sugar layer on top of ECMAScript 5.x... The above code still works with prototypes under the hoods and it works the same way as if you would code it in ECMAScript 5.x:

```
function A() {
}

A.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    console.log("hello world");
};

function B() {
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    A.prototype.doStuff.call(this);
    console.log("...and goodbye!");
};
```

Let's hope I'll need to update this answer again because ES2020 has already proposed access modifiers and we'll be able to consider JavaScript another language which fully-supports object-oriented programming!

Comment: But I dont have to do anything with javascript I just wanna know what is the Core difference between object oriented and object based language

Comment: @user2164685 The answer gives you the difference. Open your mind :) JavaScript is object oriented because it has objects, but it's not object-oriented programming because it doesn't have what an object-oriented programming language needs to have to be considered object-oriented programming!

Comment: Means you want to say the language which itself contains objects is called as object based language and the language with follow object oriented concepts is known as object oriented language...

Comment: @user2164685 Hopefully :) Great!

Comment: JavaScript has inheritance.  If you want to see it in action, just say `Object.prototype.sayHi = function() { console.log("Hi!"); }`, and now  *nearly every object in the system* can `sayHi()`.  Prototypal inheritance is inheritance -- just without the class-oriented bureaucracy.

Comment: As for polymorphism:  duck typing is the ultimate in polymorphism.  You can have two objects that *aren't even related*, but present the same interface, and you can swap out one for the other at will.  You don't get to disqualify that as "just reusing the identifier" -- because objects interpreting names differently goes to the very core of polymorphism in the first place.

Comment: @cHao About inheritance: inheritance in JavaScript is more tied to object cloning. And, obviously, prototype chain. You know that it works like inheritance, but it's not comparable to actual inheritance...

Comment: @cHao About polymorphism: maybe duck typing is "polymorphism", but are you sure it's "object-oriented polymoprhism"? I guess it's not. I dislike this trend of defending JavaScript just trying to justify features that aren't part of the language itself. "that thing smells like X"... Yes, conceptually speaking it seems to be X, but it's still a simplification....................

Comment: How are they not comparable to "real" OO principles?  What essential aspect is missing?  And how are they not baked-in features central to the very workings of the language?  The only substantial thing i see different is that most OO languages have a class to attach them to.  You seem to be arguing that that makes JS's version of them somehow not "real"; JavaScript, on the other hand, would seem to argue that discrete classes are not an essential part of OOP.

Comment: I will say, JS's attempt at emulating class-oriented programming leaves a lot to be desired.  But that layer is only there to (1) make it look a little more like Java, to (2) make JS more palatable to people stuck in a class-oriented mindset.  At JS's core is a conceptual object model so simple, and so intrinsic, one could argue it's *more* object-oriented than most languages.

Comment: @cHao First of all, I believe that this discussion is out of scope of this Q&A and a comment thread would become a war here :( 

About your thoughts, this would turn into an endless discussion. I really beleive that JavaScript is one of most misunderstood programming languages. Not only because the lack of knowledge of prototyping and duck typing capabilities by an extense number of developers, but also because there're a lot of devlopers like you that overestimate JavaScript. It's a language from 90s tied to solve simple problems (continued in the next comment)

Comment: @cHao (continuation) and now that a lot of developers understood that the Web itself is the true future of software development, they're trying to convince themself that JavaScript was created as a powerful language. 

Ok, you're right when you say extreme duck typing, dynamically-typed language gives a lot of power (or not, it's just a perception: freedom vs. more specification), but JavaScript isn't just a duck-typed language: it's a language from 90s which evolved from a very simple concept (form validation and DTHTML) (continued in the next comment)

Comment: @cHao When I see your kind of comments I believe that a lot of people didn't remember ECMA-Script 6 has classes and formal inheritance, and polymoprhism as well. Do you think they're adding that to core JS language because "classical class-based OOP fans don't understand prototypes and the power of current JS"? I don't think so: now that JS turned into a true application development language, it needs a more formal OOP. And duck-typing will be still there, because full OOP using classes is still possible. It's not JS vs classes. **It's turning JS into a powerful language without workarounds!**

Comment: ES6 is not yet worth considering as a whole.  But yes, i think *exactly* that it's adding classes because people don't understand prototypes.  To people that don't get it, JS's object model seems very clunky and bolted-on...but that's largely because at least as far as `new` etc are concerned, *it is*.  The real underlying model is way simpler and *at least* as object-oriented as Java.  Arguably more so.  But it has been constantly pooh-poohed by people who can't wrap their heads around an OO language without classes.

Comment: @cHao You'll not be the first person to say that, but I'll never admit a sentence like you said **people who can't wrap their heads around an OO language without classes**. It's not about wrapping heads: it's about avoiding workarounds to just arrive to the same point. It's my opinion and that's why I told you this Q&A and comment thread isn't the best place to discuss that. Also it can be useless to discuss that because it's an open topic...

Comment: "*BTW, ES2015 and above still lacks true encapsulation:*" see [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) from ES2022: `class Foo { #private = "you can't see this"; public = "you can see this"; }`

Answer (score 20):

**Object-based** languages include basically any language that offers the built-in ability to easily create and use objects.  There is one major criterion:

- **Encapsulation.** Objects have an API attached to them, typically in such a way that you work with the object more by *telling it what to do* than by running some function on it.

  Most object-based languages define objects in terms of "classes", which are basically blueprints for an object.  The class lays out the internal structure of the object and defines the API.

  This is not the only way, though.  In JavaScript, for example, objects don't really have "classes".  Any object can have any properties it wants.  And since functions are first-class values in JavaScript, they can be set as properties on the object, and serve as the object's API.

As far as object-based-but-not-object-oriented languages go, a good example would be Visual Basic (not the .net stuff; i'm talking about VB6 and VBA).  Classes exist, but can't inherit from each other.

**Object-oriented** languages are object-based languages that take things a step further.  They have built-in support for the two other pillars of OOP:

- **Inheritance.** Objects must have the ability to be (and be viewed as) specializations of some other object.  This means, for example, being able to define "Dog" as "Animal that can bark and fetch sticks".

  In modern languages, it typically takes the form of one object's *class* inheriting from another object's *class*.  This is not a requirement, though; contrary to what some people will try to tell you, the definition of OOP does not require classes at all.
- **Polymorphism.**  Code must be able to use an object without knowing or caring exactly what type it is.

  Most languages (especially statically typed ones) define polymorphism in terms of classes and inheritance. If you have a class B that inherits from A, code that requires a reference to an A can typically take a B instead, but not some class C that isn't related to A. Java also has the `interface` keyword, which lets you define a set of behaviors a class must implement. Any object whose class explicitly `implements X`, and thus implements the functions defined on interface X, qualifies as an instance of type X.

  Other languages, like JavaScript, let you pass any object you like. As long as the object presents the right interface, it doesn't matter exactly what kind of object it is. This is called "duck typing", and it is very nearly the purest form of polymorphism there is.

Answer (score 5):

Just using objects does not mean you are doing OOP, even in a fully OO language if you are not implementing OO techniques it is simply object-based programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 major elements that a Programming Language must conforms to in order to be a true object-oriented language. These are: Abstraction, Encapsulation, Modularity & Hierarchy.

However, we can call a Language Object based if that supports the first there elements. As soon as a programming language supports the concept of Object, inherently it supports the first three elements as they are inherent feature of an Object.

JavaScript as a language can not be said a Object Oriented but Object Based Language as it doesn't support Hierarchy (especially Inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

> OOP and OBP are types of programming languages follows different principles.

**OOP** : follows Polymorphism, Inheritance and Encapsulation(PIE).

- **Examples**: Java, .Net so on. OOP is new comparing with OBP

**OBP** : follows Polymorphism and Encapsulation.

- **Examples**: Ada, Visual Basic (VB), and Fortran 90. OBP is old

Answer (score 0):

crudely...

- object-oriented: supports encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism
- object-based: supports encapsulation

[Wikipedia - Object-Based Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-based_language)

Answer (score -4):

Object oriented programming languages follow all concepts belonging to OOP.

Object based programming language has objects ibuilt so there's no need to create objects and it also follows OOP concepts except inheritence,

Answer (score -4):

Object orientd language

```
Object-orientd language supports all the features of OOPs

Object-orientd language does not has in-built object

Object-orientd languages are C++, C#, Java etc
```

Object based language

```
Object-based language doesn't support all the features of OOPs like Polymorphism and Inheritance

Object-based language has in-built object like JavaScript has window object.

Object-based languages are JavaScript, VB etc.
```

Hope, this will clarify your doubt.